# WPF: App runs much slower in Visual Studio Debug Mode than executable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm helping fix performance issues with an old WPF application and one of the main issues that we encounter is that the app runs much slower if started in Debug Mode from Visual Studio, as compared to running the app directly from the /bin folder.

Comparison:

```
+------------+------+
| Run Mode   | Time |
+------------+------+
| Debug Mode | 106s |
| Executable | 17s  |
+------------+------+
```

As my WPF knowledge is very basic, and it's not an app I've been working on, I haven't got a clue what to look for.

Any suggestions on what may cause this difference?

PS: Start without Debugging (Ctrl+F5) runs as fast as the executable, so it seems Debug Mode overhead.

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in trying to optimize the Debug build.  It is meant to be debuggable, that automatically also makes it slow.  Only debug programs with small datasets, large ones are only good for growing a beard.  If the Debug build is slow with F5 and fast with Ctrl+F5 then look in the Output window.  Dollars to donuts you'll see a lot of stuff there, debug output and/or exception notifications.  That isn't cheap.  You are meant to take a look at it, if you don't want to see it then right-click the Output window and turn off the ticked items.

Comment: Probably caused by handled exceptions in some module. Should be fixed for VS2015 and .NET 4.6, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/performance-improvement-when-debugging-net-code-with-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 4):

Applications that run in debug mode in visual studio experience a lot of overhead with communicating with VS's debugger. Their output, state, and event are logged which reduces the speed.

I experienced this a while back when running experiments in evolutionary computing. I'd start the console app from visual studio first, create new instances by starting directly from the file system. The ones started from the filesystem would run faster and even overtake the one started in VS debug mode.

Try to be cool with it. Debug mode is always slower. If what you want is speed, i'd suggest building the project, then starting it directly from the file system.

Comment: A colleague doesn't have the same issue, its not as slow with him. If we hypothetically rule out hardware differences, may there be other factors, such as caching or reading a bloated temp folder structure, that might have an effect?

Comment: Watch your Output window while debugging. If it's flooding, you may have some bad bindings or unnecessary Debug Outs you can address. It's possible your colleague isn't experiencing the same issues if his Output window is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this difference is **all code optimizations are turned off by default in debug mode**. This is because it is easier to debug when the binary code is direct correspondence to the source code.

Comment: It's a good point, you should try running debug build by itself and release build under the debugger. That will probably give you some insight as to the cause. In my experience though differences of the magnitude you are talking about are usually the result of really bad code generating a huge number of exceptions.